# Required Internet Connection = DRM

Tags: ros, installation, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why is there no easy way to install offline? Others have asked and gotten a round-about way to accomplish it from other users. However, the people responsible for ROS should be the ones addressing this gap in openness. Some projects are standalone and specifically isolated so that a controlled software environment can be created. An internet connection compromises that goal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117816/required-internet-connection-=-drm/) by [whatthewhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/10841/whatthewhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-14

Post score: -3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no easy offline install because up to this point, nobody has needed it enough to do it themselves. Thus is the nature of open source projects. That said, there actually is an offline install method designed for the turtlebots using a ISO that enables installing an entire ROS system from a flash drive. A google search for *turtlebot iso* will turn this up. You can also download debs for later installation with `aptitude download`.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Since ROS is distributed primarily in repositories (ie users get it through aptitude), I believe the intention is that you would use traditional repository tools to install offline.

If you have installed ROS on a Ubuntu machine (and likely any *nix machine) then the .deb file for that repository is stored at /var/cache/apt/archives and you could use that .deb file to install on another machine offline.

Does this address your situation? If not, please let me know which part won't work for you.

-Tim

---

Originally posted by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) with karma: 267 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is not yet at the universal adoption phase, which unfortunately means that we do not yet have ROS CDs available in every KMart checkout aisle (much like the infamous AOL CDs we all once used to build cheap robots). This does have the upside of meaning that ROS is quite far away from being bought by Time Warner, and likely run into the ground.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3